# Ember 4.1. Django rest json api. Access field choices from OPTIONS request in Ember data model or elsewhere

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, ember.js

My DRF JSON API backend responds with a JSON on OPTIONS request.
The OPTIONS response includes field choices declared on Django model.
On my frontend, in my Ember 4.1 app with default JSONApiAdapter I want to use these exact same choices on my form select. Is there a way to access these choices on my Ember model or somewhere else? and if so, How do I do it?
Here's an example OPTIONS response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "Names List",
        "description": "API endpoint for Names",
        "renders": [
            "application/vnd.api+json",
            "text/html"
        ],
        "parses": [
            "application/vnd.api+json",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "multipart/form-data"
        ],
        "allowed_methods": [
            "GET",
            "POST",
            "HEAD",
            "OPTIONS"
        ],
        "actions": {
            "POST": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "String",
                    "required": true,
                    "read_only": false,
                    "write_only": false,
                    "label": "Name",
                    "help_text": "name",
                    "max_length": 255
                },
                "name-type": {
                    "type": "Choice",
                    "required": true,
                    "read_only": false,
                    "write_only": false,
                    "label": "Name type",
                    "help_text": "Name type",
                    "choices": [
                        {
                            "value": "S",
                            "display_name": "Short"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "L",
                            "display_name": "Long"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ime, normally `OPTIONS` requests only contain header information for allowed methods, etc.
you still need to perform `GET` to get your data.
It seems like this usage of `OPTIONS` in your question is unconventional, and will likely be an up-hill battle.

More information can be found here: https://codeburst.io/cors-story-of-requesting-twice-85219da7172d

Comment: Is it better solution to include options inside response `meta` object?

Comment: on the client-side, normally you don't touch options at all, it's supposed to all be automatic (via headers).  I wouldn't deliberately return any JSON.

Comment: As of my best research Ember does not offer that functionality. Since reading choices from OPTIONS is not in API spec, it is not implemented in Ember. The only choice I have is to return object `meta`, which is ok under JSON spec, and use it in ember. I have not done that yet :)

Comment: it's not ember-specific. ember-data uses fetch underneath: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: (though it could be that I totally don't understand what you're doing and why you're doing it).

I'd visit the ember-data channel on discord for help from an ember-data expert

Comment: Already did, thanks @NullVoxPopuli :)